# Maven dependency and repository questions

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository

I want to develop some "house" projects. This projects will use a lot of frameworks and some of those projects that I will create will be used by other projects in the future. So I will have a lot of dependencies (snapshots and/or releases) to manage.

My "question" is. Where I work we have a Nexus repo where we have our artifacts and where we store our snapshots/releases. But it I think for what I'm going to to it's a bit of overkill to install a Nexus repo, and I don't know how to configure it.

Can you give to me any ideas how I can simply solve this "problem"? Basically I want to be able to do some releases of my projects and use them by other projects in a nice way.

I don't know if it helps but I want to use bitbucket as a Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to install a Nexus, you don't have to. In fact, the default maven installation as downloaded from apache has the maven central repository preconfigured.

The first time you have to do something yourself is when you need a dependency that is not in maven central. Then you will have 2 options. (1) Checkout and build it yourself or (2) find it on a repository other than maven central and configure that repository in your maven installation - using the documentation provided in the "maven guide to mirror settings." 
 which can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Comment: I understand what you are saying but my "problem" is a bit different. Imagine that I develop a project called "project-a" and then I start developing "project-b" that needs to use "project-a" as it's dependency. How I'm going to release "project-a"? Where I'm going to "store" it? And how can I checkout my "project-b" on a different machine and continue my development on "project-b"? 
I hope to be making myself understood